# QML type to draw with QPainter

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

In QML documentation I found an example of custom type (defined from C++) to draw on it with QPainter:

Header:

```
#include <QtQuick/QQuickPaintedItem> 

class PieChart : public QQuickPaintedItem    
{
...

public:
    void paint(QPainter *painter);

...
};
```

Source:

```
void PieChart::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    QPen pen(m_color, 2);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    painter->drawPie(boundingRect().adjusted(1, 1, -1, -1), 90 * 16, 290 * 16);
}
```

How can I derive a type to draw (e.g. a line) on it asynchronously with QPainter?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple ways do draw asynchronously:

1) Draw your content into a `QImage` at some point (maybe even in a seperate thread), and in `QQuickPaintedItem::paint()`, simply draw that image.

2) Use the [QtQuick Canvas](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-canvas.html). Note that this is drawing in JavaScript, not in C++, but under the hood it is actually QPainter commands. The Canvas supports various [render strategies](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-canvas.html#renderStrategy-prop), among others doing the drawing in a dedicated thread or in the render thread